# Botão de Volume (com JSlider Circular?)

Tags: java

Olá, eu e minha equipe estamos fazendo um sintetizador para o trabalho da faculdade, no caso estou fazendo a interface gráfica e gostaria de fazer os seguintes botões:

[image: Botões]

Os botões de mixagem funcionariam como desse teclado online: [Sintetizador](https://nicroto.github.io/viktor/).

Acredito que deveria usar um JSlider Circular por baixo do botão, ou mesmo no lugar do botão, por causa de como faz girar os botões do sintetizador online que eu linkei (acredito que ficaria mais fácil para o usuário), porém, ainda não faço ideia de como fazer. Alguém sabe de algum material bom (serve até PDFs), de preferência em Português, para eu tentar aprender sobre Graphics 2D e o JSlider?

Comment: Não existe material didático pra fazer gambiarra

Comment: Eu não espero um tutorial no material, quero aprender a usar os métodos para que eu possa desenvolver "minhas gambiarras". Inclusive, se essa é uma gambiarra, me fala um método ideal de fazer...

Comment: Não acho que seja _gambi_. Você pode desenhar os botões do jeito que quer e com fundo transparente e tentar girá-la de acordo com a ação do mouse em cima delas

Comment: Dê uma olhada em: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6828684/java-mouseevent-check-if-pressed-down, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14124593/how-to-rotate-graphics-in-java e https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6828684/java-mouseevent-check-if-pressed-down

Comment: De novo a mesma pergunta? Eu ja te falei e expliquei que nao é possivel nada pronto nativamente, voce terá que escrever um componente assim na mao, pra que ficar recriando a mesma pergunta?

Comment: Outra coisa o site nao da recomendação de materiais, sua pergunta está fora do escopo. Mas já que quer tutorial, o melhor é esse aqui: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html

Comment: Articuno, refiz a pergunta porque tive que editar a outra várias vezes (pra chegar nessa), e sim, eu sei que não tem nada pronto, queria saber se dá pra fazer do jeito que eu falei, usar o Graphics 2D para editar um componente JSlider da forma que eu to pretendendo, e no caso, pedi materiais pra dar uma estudada e tentar fazer (claro que se alguém mandasse pronto seria ótimo, me pouparia bastante tempo, porém, fazer é mais divertido), inclusive, muito obrigado Marcelo Uchimura, to dando uma lida aqui e vai ser bem útil, e obrigado pelo link também Articuno, vou dar uma estudada aqui.

Comment: Nao, nao da pra fazer apenas usando graphics, eu repeti 3x que voce precisará criar um componente do zero, ja que nao quer utilizar imagens de fundo como disse na outra pergunta. Eu estou lhe dando o caminho certo, mas voce insiste em seguir pelo mais dificil, boa sorte entao. E sua pergunta continua fora do escopo de qualquer jeito, recomendo que leia [ask]

Comment: É porque eu não tinha entendido sua resposta até então... Qual seria o nível de dificuldade de criar um componente do zero (e tem alguma sugestão de como eu faria isso)?

Comment: Depende do seu nivel de conhecimento da API. Se domina a API, vc terá menos dificuldade, mas ainda terá um pouco. Agora se nao sabe nada da API, ai é melhor estudar alternativas, como usar outra API ou linguagem que suporte isso de forma mais facil pra implementar. Nunca precisei "reinventar a roda" como voce está fazendo. Por isso, antes de desenvolver alguma coisa, a gente precisa estudar a API que irá utilizar para ver se ela da suporte a isso. A curva de aprendizagem de swing é muito alta.

Comment: Beleza, vlws, eu vou dar uma pesquisada e estudar um pouco, se der certo eu posto o código aqui depois pra fechar o tópico, senão eu desisto e excluo o mesmo.

Comment: Recomendo que comece do inicio, estude a API e aprenda o basico dela, se nao souber ainda. Depois avalie se é viavel fazer isso, as vezes precisamos alterar o requisito e adapta-lo se quisermos terminar um projeto. Se tempo nao for problema pra voce, ai muda a questao, e voce pode explorar ao fundo como fazer isso do jeito que quer.